# php mail function doesnt work

Tags: php, email

if i remove $headers from mail function its working and it send $message with all the html code included in mail instead of showing table, but when i include $headers in mail function,it doesnt send mails.it doesnt even show any error.here's my code.im on working on web server.

```
<?php

    //Deal with the email

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {


    $to = 'myemail@example.com';
            $title = 'New Enquiry || example.com';

    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

     }

    $headers .= "From: " . strip_tags($email) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


    $msg = '<html><head><body><b>'.$title.'</b>

            <br>

            <table bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
            <tr>
            <td> Subject : </td>
            <td> '.$subject.'</td></tr>'

            .'<tr> <td> Contact person: </td><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>'
            .'<tr> <td> E-mail:</td><td> '.$email.'</td></tr>'
            .'<tr><td> Message : </td><td>'.$message.' </td></tr></table></body></head></html>';


     mail($to, $title, $subject, $msg, $headers);

     header( "refresh:1;url=contact-us-ok.html" );          


?>
```

Comment: @DanyCaissy Then why would it work without `$headers`?

Comment: Your HTML nesting is wrong. You can't have `<body>` inside `<head>`.

Comment: thanks man for pointing it out.and i dont know why its working without $headers,but i've read somewhere that $headers are optional.

Comment: thanks for your reply,problem solved by removing $title from function and <head> from HTML code.

Comment: The answers explain why removing `$title` is necessary. Don't you think you should accept one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mail function is defined as:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

You are sending:

```
mail($to, $title, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

It looks like you are sending the $title variable when you shouldn't be.

Comment: ok i removed $title variable.and inserted bool in front of mail,but dreamweaver shows there's syntax error.

Comment: thanks for your reply,problem solved by removing $title from function and <head> from HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

Your order of arguments to [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) is wrong. It should be:

```
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

There is no argument for a "title".

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

Side note:

- `strip_tags()` is not sufficient to prevent header injections. I suggest using a hard coded email of your own for the `From` address, instead of user input because otherwise you  can get inconsistent spam filter results and you obviously have to implement some validation to prevent the injection vulnerability.

Comment: hi i have inserted bool in front of mail,but dreamweaver shows there's syntax error.

Comment: thanks for your reply,problem solved by removing $title from function and <head> from HTML code.